# Use List or Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a program where i need to store a list of some variables.
each variables has a name and a value and i want to make a function that gets the name of a variable and returns its value:

object getValue(string name);

To do that i have two choices:

1: Store the variables in a dictionary Dictionary and then the function getValue would just fetch the variable whose key is the name i am looking for:

```
object getValue (string name) 
{
    return variablesDictionary[name].Value;
}
```

2: Store the variables in a list and then access the wanted variable through linq:

```
object getValue (string name) 
{
    return variablesList.Where(v => v.Name == name).First();
}
```

Both are very simple but the second one (linq) seems more compelling because it uses linq and also because in the first method the same name is stored in two different places which is redundant.

What is the best method with respect to best practices and performance?

Thanks

Comment: _"more compelling **because it uses linq**"_  Use linq _when it makes sense to use linq_, not just because it's there.

Comment: How many items does this collection have? Is performance important? I would normally suggest that you use a dictionary - after all, you're wanting to look items up by key. You mean `Where` rather than `Select` btw, and you could instead just pass a predicate to `First` - `return variablesList.First(v => v.Name == name);` And I agree with James - "because it uses LINQ" isn't a good reason.

Comment: you should replace `Select` with `Where`

Comment: @dotctor: Or simply use the `First` overload that takes a predicate.  Or maybe `SingleOrDefault` would be more appropriate.  Either way, yes, the LINQ is wrong here as written, and this is the wrong place to use LINQ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **definitely** use a Dictionary in this case. If you use a List and want to do a lookup, in the worst case the program has to loop over the entire list to find the right object. For a Dictionary, this is always a constant time, *irrespective* of its size.

By the way, 'uses LINQ' is not a good reason to prefer one method over the other.

Answer (score 4):

Using a dictionary is way faster than using a list, at least in any case when it matters.

The performance of a dictionary lookup is O(1), while a list search is O(n). That means that it takes the same time to find the item in the dictionary with few items as with many items, but finding them in the list takes longer the more items that you have.

For very small sets of variables the list may be slightly faster, but then they are both so fast that it doesn't matter. With many items the dictionary clearly outperforms the list.

The dictionary uses a bit more memory, but not so much. Remember that it will only store the reference to the name, it's not another copy of the string.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is *exactly what dictionaries were designed for*.

Technically, any dictionary that uses an object property as a key to that object will be "redundant" as you describe, but because `string` is a reference type, it's not like you'll be using up a huge amount of memory to store the "redundant" key.

At the cost of a few extra bytes, you get a huge performance increase.  The thing that makes dictionaries so cool is that they're [*hash tables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), so they'll always look up an element from a key quickly, no matter how big they are.  But if you use a list and try to iterate over it with LINQ, you might have 10,000 items in the list and the one you're looking for is at the end, and it will take approximately 10,000 times longer than looking it up with a Dictionary.  (For a more formal look at the math involved, try Googling "Big O notation" and "time complexity".  It's a very useful bit of theory to know about when developing software!)